# how to implement affectiva sdk in cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, cordova-plugins, affdex-sdk

I am developing a Cordova(Phonegap) hybrid project for Android and IOS platforms using jquery mobile framework I have tried using javascript version of affectiva but it does not detect camera(I have also installed cordova camera plugin) and i get the call back message camera denied. Any suggestion on how to enable affdex.CameraDetector to recognize device camera? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Javascript version of Affectiva's SDK does not work on mobile devices. This should change with a future release.